# Google PageSpeed Insights fails - Lighthouse returned error: DNS_FAILURE. DNS servers could not resolve the provided domain

Tags: google-pagespeed, lighthouse, pagespeed-insights

Error while evaluating a page using Google Page Speed Insights.
This is an intermittent issue but happened very frequently. Can someone suggest the workaround.

Full Issue Log:
500 Internal Server Error
{
  "code" : 500,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "lighthouse",
    "message" : "Lighthouse returned error: DNS_FAILURE. DNS servers could not resolve the provided domain.",
    "reason" : "lighthouseError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Lighthouse returned error: DNS_FAILURE. DNS servers could not resolve the provided domain."
}
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 500 Internal Server Error
{
  "code" : 500,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "lighthouse",
    "message" : "Lighthouse returned error: DNS_FAILURE. DNS servers could not resolve the provided domain.",
    "reason" : "lighthouseError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Lighthouse returned error: DNS_FAILURE. DNS servers could not resolve the provided domain."
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:150)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:443)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1092)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:541)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:474)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:591)

Comment: if you are getting this problem regularly you need to check your DNS settings quickly as you have a significant problem with them. What is your domain name?

Answer (score -1):

Why would you just not use chrome dev tools audit?

Comment: Use the comment section to ask more information about the question.